# What were the technological differences between Japan and the USA in World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two

Other than the nuclear bomb, I'm just curious as to why they lost WW2.

Comment: You appear to be asking two different questions. The answer to the first is not necessarily the reason for the second (which was mainly a question of resources).

Comment: It's also far too large a question to be answered in less than book length, because there were many differences, most insignificant.  You might ask about differences that  significantly affected the war.  But ultimately Japan was doomed to lose due to greater US resources.  It might not have surrendered without shock effect of the bomb, leading to either an invasion/conquest, or isolating the home islands into a "hermit kingdom" like North Korea.

Comment: @SteveBird No, I am using the second statement as the reason for why I am interested in the question

Comment: @jamesqf Perhaps you think that I am asking for why Japan lost, no I am asking for technological differences. you can direct me to resources, or specify simply for example better radar, some types of weapons used by USA, etc.

Comment: @Goldname: Maybe the reason I think you're asking why Japan lost is that you explicitly write that you're "...curious as to why they lost WW2".  But AFAIK (I'm making no claims to being an expert historian) there really were no significant technological differences.  Japan might have had a slight technical advantage when the US entered the war, due to having been at war for years while the US was unprepared.  But the US had an advantage in resources that let them produce improved weapons, like long-range bombers.

Answer (score 2):

Japan lost because they didn't have large petroleum resources nearby, and had to over-extend themselves. With sufficient petroleum, they would not have needed to expend into SE Asia, and thus would not have needed to attack the Americans in the Philippines and Pearl Harbor.

There were technical differences abound, but really both Japan and the US had nearly equivalent technology. They lost because of over-extension and oil.